# How to hide an html5 video on iphone when it's done playing?

Tags: iphone, html, html5-video, mobile-safari

iPhone plays the html5 video full-screen and obviously in it's own player which has nothing to do with the browser DOM. Inconvenient, awkward, reminds a bit of IE in old times, but ok. The question is about something else - the problem is that after it is done playing it doesn't go away and stays there full-screen and stopped at last frame, is there a way to make it go away automatically, so that the DOM logic could proceed somehow?

Comment: with the use of notificationcenter you can achieve this

Comment: notificationcenter? How do you mean?

Comment: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(VideoExit:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification" object:nil];

Comment: The question was about how to do this in the browser. Using JavaScript maybe?

Or is it possible to invoke instructions like this from JS?

Comment: emmm.... sorry have no idea abt that :(